# Chrome macOS video frame format support, why NV12 is out of consideration

Tags: macos, camera, chromium

I don't know why Chrominum didn't take the most popular format kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange(NV12) into the consideration,
this is the latest code I cloned today:
In the video_capture_device_avfoundation_mac.mm, it only takes two 422 formats and MJPEG into the consideration:

```
// This function translates Mac Core Video pixel formats to Chromium pixel
// formats.
media::VideoPixelFormat FourCCToChromiumPixelFormat(FourCharCode code) {
  switch (code) {
    case kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8:
      return media::PIXEL_FORMAT_UYVY;
    case kCMPixelFormat_422YpCbCr8_yuvs:
      return media::PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2;
    case kCMVideoCodecType_JPEG_OpenDML:
      return media::PIXEL_FORMAT_MJPEG;
    default:
      return media::PIXEL_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
  }
}
```

I tried video tool box VTCompressionSession, it cannot create MJPEG encoder due to not supported, no hardware, not even soft one

Comment: The question '*why*' is kindof strange in this context. This method has never used `NV12`, most likely because nobody needed this. Note that [h264_vt_encoder.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/media/+/master/cast/sender/h264_vt_encoder.cc) switched to `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` [in 2015](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/media/+/c11d9929d0d6d6c84c034525d173ce7e5fdcdd9c).

Comment: Thanks Alex, the reason I ask why because in the chromium preference color space, it defines:
namespace media {

// This list is ordered by precedence of use.
static VideoPixelFormat const kSupportedCapturePixelFormats[] = {
    PIXEL_FORMAT_I420,  PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12, PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12,
    PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21,  PIXEL_FORMAT_UYVY, PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2,
    PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB24, PIXEL_FORMAT_ARGB, PIXEL_FORMAT_MJPEG,
};

NV12 is more preferred than UYVY and YUY2 (ahead of)

Comment: My hypothesis (after looking at history of `video_capture_device_avfoundation_mac.mm`) is that src/media/capture/video likes that the Mac built-in camera can be treated same as Linux webcams, which all prefer 422 formats.

Comment: Right, my virtual camera used to be using NV12, avfoundation application doesn't have problem in using it, but failed with test.webrtc.org, after I updated to 422 UYVY, now 320x240 passed its test, but 640x480 and 720P are failing, not sure if Chrome layer require MJPEG for VGA and plus.

Comment: Check resolution 320x240
[ INFO ] cameraName: Steven Cam930e (6D76:CC00)
[ INFO ] actualVideoWidth: 320
[ INFO ] actualVideoHeight: 240
[ INFO ] mandatoryWidth: 320
[ INFO ] mandatoryHeight: 240
[ INFO ] isMuted: false
[ INFO ] testedFrames: 291
[ INFO ] blackFrames: 0
[ INFO ] frozenFrames: 0
[ INFO ] Not available: encodeSetupTimeMs, avgEncodeTimeMs, minEncodeTimeMs, maxEncodeTimeMs, avgInputFps, minInputFps, maxInputFps, avgSentFps, minSentFps, maxSentFps
[ OK ] Captured video using expected resolution.
Check resolution 640x480
Check resolution 1280x720